# send a simple message to an email using laravel 4.2 and mailtrap

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

Im trying to send an email and im using mailtrap for this. the email im trying to send is just a plain messgae let's say , "You have been emailed!" but i can't seem to make it using laravel 4.2 here is my `mail.php`

```
return array(
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'mailtrap.io',
    'port' => 2525,
    'from' => array('address' => 'example@gmail.com', 'name' => 'SSIMS'),
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
    'username' => 'sadasdadsadadsad', //not my real username
    'password' => '341ssfsdf2342', //not my real password
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
 );
```

just copied this from `mailtrap.io` then i don't know how to send the email using laravel. The thing is im not sending any views im just trying to send some simple message so in the documentation of 4.2 i saw that there is this `Mail::raw()` method so i used it like this

then when i tried it i got an error saying

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::raw()

here is the controller that handles it (i omitted the other functions here)

```
<?php

class POrder extends \BaseController
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $title = "Purchase Order Page";
        $modules = prchorder::lists('ModuleName','ModuleID');
        return View::make('ssims.purchaseorder_index',compact('title','modules'));
    }

    public function chkInput()
    {
        session_start();
        $getsCapt = $_SESSION["captcha"];

        $rules = array(
            'ModuleInfo'      => 'required',
            'Quantity'        => 'required|numeric|digits_between:2,5',
            'SchoolEmail'     => 'required|min:10|max:254|email',
            'SupplierEmail'   => 'required|min:10|max:254|email',
            'capt'            => 'required|numeric'
        );

        $messages = array(
            'ModuleInfo.required'   => 'Please Select a Module.',
            //'SchoolEmail.email'     => 'Please Enter a Valid Email for the School Email.',
            //'SupplierEmail.email'   => 'Please Enter a Valid Email for the Supplier Email.',
            'capt.numeric'          => 'CAPTCHA code must be a number.',
            'SchoolEmail.same'      => 'School Email cannot be same with the Supplier Email.',
            'SupplierEmail.same'    => 'Supplier Email cannot be same with the School Email.',
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
        $uCapt = Input::get('capt');

        // process the inputs given by the user
        if ($validator->fails()) { 
            return Redirect::to('purchase_order')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
        } else {
            if ($uCapt == $getsCapt) {
                $sEmail    = Input::get('SupplierEmail');

                //return Redirect::to('purchase_order');
                Mail::raw('Text to e-mail', function($message) {
                    $message->from('sample@gmail.com', 'Laravel');
                    $message->to('sample1@gmail.com')->cc('sample2@yahoo.com');
                });
            } else {
                return Redirect::to('purchase_order')
                    ->withErrors('CAPTCHA code does not match')
                    ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Any ideas on what i may be doing wrong? or how can i make it work? thanks

Comment: What does your controller that handles this look like?

Comment: i added it to the question. thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert with Laravel 4.2, but are you sure Mail::raw() is supported in that version? Looking at the documentation it only became a thing in Laravel 5.0 and up, http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/mail

Comment: ohh yes. my bad. i got more problem now lol :)

Comment: Have added an example of using `Mail::send()` instead of `Mail::raw()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that Laravel 4.2 doesn't support `Mail::raw()`, simply replace it with `Mail::send()` like so:

```
Mail::send('emails.example', array('a_value' => 'you_could_pass_through'), function($message)
{
    $message->to('sample1@gmail.com', 'John Smith')->cc('sample2@yahoo.com')->subject('Example!');
});
```

In this example, `emails.example` refers to a view called example in an emails folder with the rest of your views. `array('a_value' => 'you_could_pass_through')` is simply that - an array that passes data in to view. If you have no data you want to pass in then simply use `array()` as it is a required part of `Mail::send()`.

The rest is just setting the to and cc fields, the from information will already come form your `mail.php` file which you have set up.

Comment: when if out my view in the `emails.example` im having some problems with it. saying `Unsupported operand types` here is the form in my view 9

Comment: You should create a question for that and provide the code you are using that causes the error.

Comment: @James How could I send email for local development without using Mail::pretend() in 4.2? Because I am using Windows. It throws Swift_TransportException "The system cannot find the path specified. ]". I guess this happens because of my config 'driver' => 'sendmail', 'host' => 'localhost', 'port' => 25, 'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'.

Comment: @MithunJack you will need to post your own question as the question above is completely different from OPs. Also, what are you still doing on 4.2, we are up to Laravel 7.X now, make the most of the new features and security updates and update your application!

Comment: @James Yeah.. I can understand. we usually work in 5.8. I'm doing nothing in 4.2 and I don't want to. It's client suggestion. They just want us to modify their flow in 4.2. That's it. Thanks for the reply